# Rootdir meaning in Android

Tags: linux, mount

So here these are two quotes which I think describe well what the root dir is :

> **rootdir**: the root directory (`/`). All files/folders/filesystems are stored in or mounted under rootdir. On Android, the filesystem may be either `rootfs` or the `system` partition.

From [here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/docs/boot.md#terminologies)

And the second one from [superuser forums](https://superuser.com/questions/1072071/linux-folder-and-root-folder)

> - That means it is the ultimate parent or grandparent or grand grandparent of any file or directory you can find on your system.
> - It contains all the files necessary for the system to work such as boot files, libraries, packages, essential binaries, system configuration, user files and temporary files.

But I am a bit confused : if I am correct the rootdir is the *place* where all filesystems are mounted. But in Android that does not happen (at least Android 10+) : the root dir is `/system` however some directories are not mounted in the system directory. Example : `data` which is mounted... well under `/data` (and not `/system/data`) or also the `vendor` partition, mounted under `/vendor`. So I deduced that not all directories are mounted in the root dir, here `/system`. Why ?

Comment: Well from multiple sentences in [magisk repo docs](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/docs/boot.md). See 
**SAR**: System-as-root. That is, the device uses `system` as rootdir instead of `rootfs`

because rootdir is in `system`

Comment: Are you referring to system_as_root systems? Then this is a misunderstood on your side, because on such systems the system.img is not mounted to `/system` instead it is mounted to `/` -> the mount point has also changed. See https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions/system-as-root#sar-partitioning

Comment: `/` is always the "root dir" within a context of concern. The fact that Android has its system stuff placed in a filesystem/partition that gets mounted on `/system/` doesn't make it the "root dir". It's just a taste / preference of file hierarchy.

Comment: @Robert oh I didn't know that. So, a system_as_root device mounts the system.img to `/` and then other partitions such as data or vendor are mounted under that mount point of system.img ? And just another question : since system files are under `/system` I guess that the system.img file is actually *made* of a system dir which itself contains system files and that these system files are not in the *root* of the system image since otherwise all system files would be mounted to `/`. Am I correct ? Sorry for my bad English :/

Comment: In other words, the "system filesystem" in "normal" Linux is usually (if not always) mounted on `/`, while on Android, the "system filesystem" is usually (if not always) mounted on `/system`, while its "root filesystem" (i.e. the filesystem that is mounted on `/`) is often a `tmpfs` (IIRC) that has several directories (`system`, `data`, etc.) created on it that are used as mountpoints for the various partitions/filesystems of the OS.

Comment: As you can see, it's mainly due to the fact that Android adopts the system / data / etc. "separation" hierarchy / partitioning. Actually even in "normal" Linux setup, some people would have the content of `/usr/` or `/home/` or some other placed in a separated filesystem/partition. (So "system filesystem" in "normal" Linux is just a loose analogy, the hierarchy design is simply different in them.)

Comment: Ok so when Android boots basically, it mounts a tempfs on `/` and then mounts system.img on it, alongside with other partitions and assign a usually assign a directory per filesystem. Am I correct ?

Comment: I'm not gonna write it as an answer since it's usually a wasted effort in case of technical topics. But if you are familiar with C/C++ syntax, start reading [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/init/first_stage_init.cpp#174) what Android's `init` does after the kernel hands over charge to it on boot. If not, read at least the basics of [`switch_root`](https://landley.net/writing/rootfs-programming.html). You'll get a very clear picture of what's happening.

Comment: As a bonus, you may want to read [Android device partitions and filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-android-device-partitions-and-filesystems.3586565/) and [Android boot process](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux.3785254/)

Comment: you can mount any partition to any directory, location doesn't matter. what you have quoted is just a description of google's choice for android (which has changed between versions) not a law. rootdir meaning is not different from linux it's always `/`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I understood everything